# Import global constant from conftest in subdirectory is not recognized, only outermost conftest is

Tags: python, pytest

I have a repo whose structure looks a bit like this.

```
repo/
-- test
  -- conftest.py
  -- test_1.py
  -- classifier
     -- conftest.py
     -- test_classifier.py
```

I put some global constants (let's say `CONSTANT1`) only used in `test_classifier.py` inside `test/classifier/conftest.py`. I call them inside `test_classifier.py` and they are not recognized.
`ImportError: cannot import name 'CONSTANT1' from 'conftest' (/repo/test/conftest.py)`. The conftest inside `/repo/test/classifier/conftest.py` is not detected, only the outermost conftest is. How to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're importing CONSTANT1 from the wrong conftest. It would help to see your code but I think replacing `from test.conftest import CONSTANT1` by `from test.classifier.conftest import CONSTANT1` should work

Comment: IDK if it's official, but as per my understanding, PyTest discourages the use of imports from `conftest.py` modules, as fixtures are available hierarchically from respective `conftest` modules in parent folders.

Comment: Exactly, I think @eng2019 expected to have the behavior of fixtures with a constant. So an alternative solution is to put the constant into a fixture

Answer (score 1):

You could define a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/4.6.x/fixture.html), which would contain your constants.

```py
# in test/conftest.py

@pytest.fixture
def constants():
    """ Global constants """
    return {
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2
    }
```

You can later override it in your sub-test folders' `conftest.py`

```py
# in test/classifier/conftest.py

@pytest.fixture
def constants(constants):
    """ Overriden constants """
    constants["B"] = 5
    del constants["A"]
    ...
```

This way could seem a bit complex, because you have to maintain proper hierarchy for your test modules, but that is also a feature of **well-designed** tests.